# How to write double summation in Gurobi Python

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to Gurobi and I would like to check if my code for the following formulation is correct.

[image]

```
m = Model("MIP1")

m.setObjective(quicksum(c[s]*x[a,p] for a in A for p in P for s in S), GRB.MINIMIZE)

m.addConstr(quicksum(Q[a]*x[a,p] for a in A for p in P <= K[s] for s in S,"c0")

m.addConstr(quicksum(x[a,p] for p in P)==1 for a in A,"c1")
```

Comment: You didn't share how the variables are defined. Please always post a minimal reproducible example.